# Can't log in service princible from VSTS, but works in TFS and Azure Portal state success

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, service-principal

I'm sitting in a project where I will move from TFS to VSTS so we do have a working release definition.

But when I try deploying a service fabric cluster i get the following error:

> 2018-08-28T09:02:59.8922249Z ##[error]An error occurred attempting to acquire an Azure Active Directory token. Ensure that your service endpoint is configured properly with valid credentials. Error message: Exception calling "AcquireToken" with "3" argument(s): "AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access '< *service principle Id* >'.
>
> Trace ID: < *guid1 is here* >
>
> Correlation ID: < *guid2 is here* >

Then I go to the azure portal -> AAD -> Sign In -> look up my specific sign in (based on correlation Id) and there it state that Sign-in status is Success

Considering this works for our TFS instance i assume the service principle is correctly set up. But since the build/deploy agents is now on a VM in azure instead of on prem for TFS, is there anything i need to change?

Traffic should be OK, i can navigate to the https-adress to the cluster from the VM with agents.

I've tried google it, but to no success so hopefully someone can point me to the right direction where to look.

And in portal, 'MFA is required' is no, so multi factor should not be neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using certificate based authentication instead of using AAD Authentication in the service endpoint configuration.

Reference the same issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/7714

If that still not work, just try to create a new endpoint, then try it again.